# Did Weed from Legendary Moonlight Sculptor ever meet Prina's friend from planting in Valley of Death quest?

Tags: moonlight-sculptor

Did Weed from Legendary Moonlight Sculptor ever meet Prina's friend from planting in Valley of Death quest?